# Using MySQL ODBC Driver in SSIS

Tags: mysql, windows, ssis

I have installed the [mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-winx64.msi](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=453005) driver and confirmed it installed successfully:

[image]

However, in the ODBC Data Source Administrator (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) the driver is not listed in the Drivers tab so I can not add a User Data Source.

Thanks, Kate.

Comment: You installed the 64 bit driver but you're looking in the 32 bit folder (yes, it's called SysWOW64 but that's the 32 bit location)

Comment: Turning @billinkc's comment into an action question: If you install the 32-bit ODBC driver from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/, does the driver show up in the ODBC Data Source administrator?

Comment: I have tried using odbcad32.exe under both System32 and SysWOW64.  According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976, the "User DSN" lists 32 and 64 bit drivers wheras the "System DSN" lists only the 32 bit drivers.  The MySQL driver is not listed in either one.

Comment: @Kate Did you ever get a solution to this ?